# Kafka Pausing partition and taking long time (10 min) in resuming it again

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am using spring kafka with following configurations :

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, 
environment.getProperty("kafka.url"));
props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
StringDeserializer.class);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
props.put("specific.avro.reader", true);
props.put("schema.registry.url", 
environment.getProperty("schema.registry.url"));
props.put("session.timeout.ms", 120000);
props.put("request.timeout.ms", 300000);
props.put("max.partition.fetch.bytes", "10240");
props.put("max.poll.interval.ms", 120000);
props.put("max.poll.records", 100);
```

And

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, 
List<AlertNotificationPayload>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, 
List<AlertNotificationPayload>> factory = new 
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(10);
}
```

and as soon as I start the server, the consumers start consuming the messages but after a while, f**ew partitions gets paused and doesn't resume for almost 9-10 min**. The processing time in the consumer thread is in milliseconds and have separate thread for processing. I have tried multiple combinations of configurations but nothing worked.

I have also tried to use the setting **factory.getContainerProperties().setPauseEnabled(false);**
which stops the pause/resume but than the rebalance starts happening after some time and sooner and later the **consumer gets died and after some time the consumer group has no consumer left**.

I am using following versions :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
         <version>1.1.3.RELEASE</version> //tried latest one as well
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-connect-quickstart</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Please help.

Comment: how many partition does topic has?

Comment: Topic has 10 partitions

Comment: and you are having one consumer group with 10 threads

Comment: Yes, I am using concurrency as 10 which creates 10 thread of the same consumer instance.

Comment: That's too old, already out of support Spring for Apache Kafka. Everybody is advised to upgrade at least to the latest `1.3.x`: there are plenty of fixes in the Apache Kafka client and respective improvement in the Spring for Apache Kafka. Of course, would be better to upgrade to the latest clients at all: they can talk to older brokers anyway.

Comment: I have fixed the issue. It was the processing logic which not running asynchronously even though I was using @Async annotation. I have moved the logic to ExecutorService with fixed thread pool and now I am not facing any lags.